# Share button is not visible in Dynamics CRM 365 views even for a system admin role

Tags: view, share, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, missing-features

I am navigating through a Dynamics CRM 365 app with system admin privileges.
When I am trying to share a view with another user, the share option is not visible in the menu.

Actual options:
[image]
Expected is:
[image]

I have verified the security roles and feature settings. Everything is in place.

Comment: Ever found a slolution for this??

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you don't own the view, and you haven't been given sharing rights.

Have the owner of the view or someone with the rights to do so, to update your view permissions so you can also share the view.

Being a Sys Admin is irrelevant on Personal Views.